# how can I bind ajax event to selectManyMenu component in primefaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, selectmanymenu

Can I modify SelectManyMenu component like autoComplete component in primefaces. In detail, instead of fetching all data to SelectManyMenu component at one time, I want to fetch the data according to the user's inputs (letters).I want to fetch data in lazy mode.

Below code is not working..."Key up" event is not catched.

```
<p:SelectManyMenu value="EmployeeList" var="list">
<f:selectItems itemLabel="list.surname" itemValue="list.id"/>
<p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{bean.doSomething}"/>
</p:SelectManyMenu>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I understand that you want to use autocomplete feature with selectManyMenu. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks. It is right.So, I modified and specified my question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should attach the `<p:ajax>` Tag to the `<f:selectItems>` directly.

```
<f:selectItems itemLabel="list.surname" itemValue="list.id">
   <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{bean.doSomething}"/>
</f:selectItems>
```

Give it a try and let me know if that was the problem.

Comment: Thanks LarsBauer, but problem continues. After I implement your code trick, jsf gaves this ERROR : "Unable to attach behavior to nonClientBehaviorHolder parent".

Comment: This error means that you can not attach the ajax component on the selectItems Element. Unfortunately my idea was wrong. But the selectItems do get displayed correctly?

Comment: Can you provide your stacktrace or the exact error message?